# Moving Large and frequently updating MySQL table with composite key to HDFS

Tags: mysql, hdfs, hbase, sqoop

I have MySQL Inventory table which don't have Auto Increment Id but has composite key and last modified date(YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS) and will update very frequently.It has last 3 years data around 10 million records.

I want to move this data to HDFS by using Sqoop or some other way. Please suggest some approach.

Answer (score 0):

Check this sqoop code below (that I use in similar tasks) based on `--lastmodified`: I want to assume here that you may have a date-like column to use with the `--check-column` argument.

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://<server>:3306/db \
--username=your_username \
-P \
--table=your_table \
--append \
--incremental lastmodified \
--check-column creation_date \
--last-value "YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS.x" \
--split-by some_numeric_id_column \
--target-dir /user/dir \
--num-mappers <MAPPER#>
```